# Windows Git Can't Open custom Diff Tool

Tags: windows, git

I have been struggling with this for hours. I'm just trying to get git to open a custom diff tool (Win 7 64bit). I'm not even in a repo, I'm just trying to launch it. Here's my config:

```
[diff]
tool = bc3
[difftool]
prompt = false
[difftool "bc3"]
cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
prompt = false
[merge]
tool = bc3
[mergetool]
prompt = false
keepBackup = false
[mergetool "bc3"]
cmd = \"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
trustExitCode = true
```

Executing this command with two test files though the git bash does nothing, no error, just nothing.

git difftool test.txt test2.txt

Comment: [This BC3 example](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs) for your config options (might have to search down to the git section) shows `git difftool` only taking one file argument. Have you tried it with just `git difftool test.txt`?

Comment: If I do that I get this: usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

Comment: [This example](http://www.jonathansewell.co.uk/index.php/2011/01/06/setting-up-git-in-windows-7/) uses a `$PWD` before the file paths. Might give that a shot? Sorry I can't be more help. I'm not a windows git user. I'm mostly just hoping one of these will inspire a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This page (http://www.learnphpbasics.com/php-reference/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool.html) suggests using Cygwin's `cygpath` to help resolve path discrepancies.  Example:

```
git config --global mergetool.fooTool.cmd 'fooTool.exe "$(cygpath -wla $BASE)" "$(cygpath -wla $LOCAL)" "$(cygpath -wla $REMOTE)" "$(cygpath -wla $MERGED)"'
```